# Replace NA's belonging to one column with values from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have following data frame (named as 'df'), with columns names as ID, org1 and org2.

Structure:

```
 ID  org1  org2
 1    C1   NA
 2    C2   NA
 3    C3   C3
 4    C4   C4
 5    C1   NA
 6    NA   C2
 7    NA   C4
 8    NA   NA
 9    NA   NA
 10   C3   C3
```

Now, I want org1 to acquire values from org2 in case a 'NA' in org1 eg: ID 6

Expected output:

```
 ID  org1  org2
 1    C1   NA
 2    C2   NA
 3    C3   C3
 4    C4   C4
 5    C1   NA
 6    C2   C2
 7    C4   C4
 8    NA   NA
 9    NA   NA
 10   C3   C3
```

I tired the following:

```
   df$org1[is.na(df$org1)] <- as.character(df$org2[is.na(df$org1)])
```

referring to the following: [Replace NA in column with value in adjacent column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629885/replace-na-in-column-with-value-in-adjacent-column)

But this yielded the following error:

```
  Warning message:
  In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(df$org1),  :invalid factor level, NA generated
```

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and is there a better solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `factor` columns to `character` class by looping through the `factor` columns with `lapply`.

```
  df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], as.character)
```

and then we can either use `pmax`.  The `pmax` will get the row wise max element between the two columns.  As the 'org2' is almost identical with that of 'org1' except for the `NA` values, `pmax` with `na.rm=TRUE` remove the NA element when there is one NA and non-NA, or if there are two NAs return NA, or have both non-NA identical return the unique element.

```
df1$org1 <- do.call(pmax, c(df1[-1], list(na.rm=TRUE)))
df1
#   ID org1 org2
#1   1   C1 <NA>
#2   2   C2 <NA>
#3   3   C3   C3
#4   4   C4   C4
#5   5   C1 <NA>
#6   6   C2   C2
#7   7   C4   C4
#8   8 <NA> <NA>
#9   9 <NA> <NA>
#10 10   C3   C3
```

or use logical index based on `is.na`, subset the 'org1' based on index and replace it with the corresponding elements of 'org2'.

```
 ind <- is.na(df1$org1)
 df1$org1[ind] <- df1$org2[ind]
```

---

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned in the comments, we can `data.table` for faster assignment.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), using the logical condition in 'i', we assign the 'org1' as 'org2' that corresponds to 'i'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(org1), org1 := org2]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, org1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,   
 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L), .Label = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"),
 class = "factor"), 
org2 = structure(c(NA, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, 2L
), .Label = c("C2", "C3", "C4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"org1", "org2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Or `setDT(df)[is.na(org1), org1 := org2]`

Comment: I got 15 warnings, and this didnt help

Comment: @user3875610  Based on the input data (assuming you have factor columns from the error), I am not getting any warnings.

Comment: @ akrun, yes it has factors but i tired on a sample data it worked thanks, although I found David's solution a lot more easy.  Akrun can you explain what exactly your code did

Comment: Thanks akrun and David, both your solutions worked!!

Answer (score 0):

The options(stringAsFactors =F) will make all the columns into string(as.character)

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
mydf <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, org1 = c('C1','C2','C3','C4','C1',NA,NA,NA,NA,'C3'),
                   org2 = c(NA,NA,'C3','C4',NA,'C2','C4',NA,NA,'C3'))
mydf$org1[is.na(mydf$org1)] <- mydf$org2[is.na(mydf$org1)]
```

Comment: This was already introduced in the other answer just without using `which`, which is redundant.

Comment: Yeah which is redundant, made the chnges

Comment: But that is already present in the other answer, as already mentioned.