# Omit numerous NA values

Tags: r

I have `DF` like:

```
A  B  C  D | Va
NA 2  NA 3 | x
1  2  3  4 | x
NA 5  5  2 | x 
4  3  2  1 | x
```

It is needed it to be like:

```
A  B  C  D | Va
1  2  3  4 | x
4  3  2  1 | x
```

The aim of is to calculate `Va` value. I have already calculate it by some rules previously (lets name it `Vb`), but it has low quality. Therefore, I need to calculate `Va` to get better values, where I can (where there is no `NA` in row). Then I need to get `V` vector, where `Va` calculated for some rows and `Vb` everywhere else. Illustration of what I need:

```
Va  Vb  ->  V
NA  2   ->  2
1   2   ->  1
NA  2   ->  2
1   2   ->  1
```

So, I have 2 questions:

1) How to rescale my original `DF` to some `newDF`, where each row has no NAs with respect to original index in `DF`?

2) I have tried `Va[is.na(Va)] <- Vb` to test `NA` replacement with `Vb` values (low quality model). It worked even with message about different length/number of replacements. Is it ok to use it to get what I need or maybe there is something better?

Comment: you may wish to use the function: complete.cases

Comment: you can also use: `na.omit`

Comment: `na.omit(DF)` can do. Example: `na.omit(head(airquality, 10))`

Comment: For the second question have a look at `ifelse()` : `DF$V <- ifelse(is.na(DF$Va), DF$Vb, DF$Va)`

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34979861/2204410) for several alternatives to your 2nd question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` and `is.na` to subset the rows of "DF"

```
DF[!rowSums(is.na(DF)),]
#   A B C D Va
#2 1 2 3 4  x
#4 4 3 2 1  x
```