# Replacing NA with values in the adjacent column

Tags: r, replace, na

I have a dada frame this is a small part:

```
namess[270:285,]
    first_name   last_name
270          R       Horne
271          T           H
272          A      McEvoy
273   Aumoitte        <NA>
274      Johin        <NA>
275  Waydelick        <NA>
276   Vigneron        <NA>
277  Sautereau        <NA>
278      Johin        <NA>
279   Aumoitte        <NA>
280    Georges Taillandier
281    Fernand        Sanz
282       John        Lake
283      Louis     Bastien
284      Louis  Hildebrand
285    Daumain        <NA>
```

I would like to replace every NA value in the column named last_name with the  value in the column first_name.
I saw a similar post  in this is the link

[Replace NA in column with value in adjacent column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629885/replace-na-in-column-with-value-in-adjacent-column)

I tried using what they suggeted

```
namess$last_name[is.na(namess$last_name)] <- as.character(namess$last_name[is.na(namess$last_name)])
```

It didn't change anything, both of the columns are character type so its not a problem of being a factor type variable

Comment: You are replacing the NA values with themselves. Try `namess$last_name[is.na(namess$last_name)] <- as.character(namess$first_name[is.na(namess$last_name)])`

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629885/replace-na-in-column-with-value-in-adjacent-column?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(namess)`), in the `i`, we use the logical condition (`is.na(last_name)`) and assign (`:=`) those elements in 'first_name' that corresponds to the condition to 'last_name'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(namess)[is.na(last_name), last_name := first_name]
namess
#    first_name   last_name
# 1:          R       Horne
# 2:          T           H
# 3:          A      McEvoy
# 4:   Aumoitte    Aumoitte
# 5:      Johin       Johin
# 6:  Waydelick   Waydelick
# 7:   Vigneron    Vigneron
# 8:  Sautereau   Sautereau
# 9:      Johin       Johin
#10:   Aumoitte    Aumoitte
#11:    Georges Taillandier
#12:    Fernand        Sanz
#13:       John        Lake
#14:      Louis     Bastien
#15:      Louis  Hildebrand
#16:    Daumain     Daumain
```

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` should give you what you're looking for here, though I can't say for certain without a reproducible example:

`namess$last_name <- ifelse(is.na(namess$last_name), namess$first_name, namess$last_name)`

Comment: A more `R` way of doing this would be to utilize subsetting--see the other answer linked in the comments above.

Comment: You're right — I suggested `ifelse` because I think it's a bit more legible, and its lack of repetition doesn't lend itself quite as much to the kinds of copy/pasting errors that led OP astray in the first place.