# Replace Zero by value of another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

This post similar with this post 
[Replace NA in column with value in adjacent column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629885/replace-na-in-column-with-value-in-adjacent-column)
But now if x6=0, it must be return by value of x5.
If i do so

```
mydat$X6[0(mydat$X6)] <- mydat$X5[0(mydat$X6)]
```

of course i have this Error: `attempt to apply non-function`

```
 mydat=structure(list(ItemRelation = c(158200L, 158204L), DocumentNum = c(1715L, 
                                                                         1715L), CalendarYear = c(2018L, 2018L), X1 = c(0L, 0L), X2 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                        0L), X3 = c(0L, 0L), X4 = c(NA, NA), X5 = c(107L, 105L), X6 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        0)), .Names = c("ItemRelation", "DocumentNum", "CalendarYear", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -2L))
```

How to replace zero by x6 on x5 value to get derided output

```
  ItemRelation DocumentNum CalendarYear X1 X2 X3 X4  X5 X6
1       158200        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 107 107
2       158204        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 105 105
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a logical `vector` and use that to subset both the replacement column and the replacee column to get the lengths equal while doing the assignment operation

```
i1 <- mydat$X6 == 0
mydat$X6[i1] <- mydat$X5[i1]
```

---

The `0(mydat$X6)` syntax is not clear - may be representation of a pseudo function

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `replace`, i.e.

```
mydat$X6 <- with(mydat, replace(X6, X6 == 0, X5[X6 == 0]))

#  ItemRelation DocumentNum CalendarYear X1 X2 X3 X4  X5  X6
#1       158200        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 107 107
#2       158204        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 105 105
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?ifelse`

```
mydat$X6 <- ifelse(mydat$X6 == 0, mydat$X5, mydat$X6)

#  ItemRelation DocumentNum CalendarYear X1 X2 X3 X4  X5  X6
#1       158200        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 107 107
#2       158204        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 105 105
```

---

looking at the benchmarks for a larger dataset. Ifelse seems to perform slower than the other 2.

```
mydat <- data.frame(X6=1:999999,X5=sample(0:1,999999,replace = T))

akrun <- function(mydat) {
    i1 <- mydat$X6 == 0
mydat$X6[i1] <- mydat$X5[i1]
}

sotos <- function(mydat) {
    mydat$X6 <- with(mydat, replace(X6, X6 == 0, X5[X6 == 0]))
}

elrico <- function(mydat) {
    mydat$X6 <- ifelse(mydat$X6 == 0, mydat$X5, mydat$X6)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(elrico(mydat),akrun(mydat),sotos(mydat), times = 100)

#Unit: milliseconds
#          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
# elrico(mydat) 42.809477 47.591964 56.814627 49.750948 51.972969 148.7152   100   c
#  akrun(mydat)  5.068961  5.206103  8.277144  5.399385  9.516853 106.4254   100 a  
#  sotos(mydat)  7.966428  8.199167 16.903062 11.996958 13.774511 110.4206   100  b
```

So if you need speed and working with lager datasets take akrun's or sotos solution. Else, you can take mine which is IMO syntactically the most "beautiful".