# Overwriting only NAs in column A with values from column B

Tags: r

I have column `A`and column `B` in a dataframe:

```
A = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1559401558, 1559413729, 1559417798), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")

B = structure(c(1559379600, 1559388600, 1559397600, 1559406600, 1559415600, 
1559424600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
>
```

As you can see, only column A has missing Dates. I want now, that only the missing Dates in `A`are replaced with related values (same indices) in `B`. I know this should work with indices, but I can't find a solution for this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15629885/5325862

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Base R:

```
A[is.na(A)] <- B[is.na(A)]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr) 
coalesce(A, B)
```

As @RuiBarradas mentioned in the comments, we can set the `tz` to NULL before doing the `coalesce`

```
library(lubridate)
coalesce(A, `tz<-`(B, ""))
```

Comment: Note that `A` doesn't have a timezone assigned, so the result may be a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(A = A, B = B) %>%
 mutate(A = ifelse(is.na(A), B, A))
```